# Upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04 fails with a python problem

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, upgrade, python

When I run sudo do-release-upgrade it aborts with:

```
Could not calculate the upgrade 

An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade. 

If none of this applies, then please report this bug using the 
command 'ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core' in a terminal. If 
you want to investigate this yourself the log files in 
'/var/log/dist-upgrade' will contain details about the upgrade. 
Specifically, look at 'main.log' and 'apt.log'.
```

When I look in main.log I see the following which may indicate I have a problem with python ending with an abort.

```
2021-05-11 19:24:02,331 INFO checking for python-dbg (auto_inst=False)
2021-05-11 19:24:02,331 INFO checking for python-doc (auto_inst=False)
2021-05-11 19:24:02,331 INFO checking for python-minimal (auto_inst=False)
2021-05-11 19:24:02,331 INFO installing python-is-python2 because python-minimal was installed
2021-05-11 19:24:02,331 DEBUG Installing 'python-is-python2' (python-minimal was installed on the system)
2021-05-11 19:24:02,378 INFO removing python-minimal because python-is-python2 is being installed
2021-05-11 19:24:02,378 DEBUG Removing 'python-minimal' (python-is-python2 is being installed on the system)
2021-05-11 19:24:02,420 INFO failed to remove python-minimal
2021-05-11 19:24:02,420 INFO checking for python-dev (auto_inst=False)
2021-05-11 19:24:02,420 INFO installing python-dev-is-python2 because python-dev was installed
2021-05-11 19:24:02,420 DEBUG Installing 'python-dev-is-python2' (python-dev was installed on the system)
2021-05-11 19:24:02,461 INFO removing python-dev because python-dev-is-python2 is being installed
2021-05-11 19:24:02,462 DEBUG Removing 'python-dev' (python-dev-is-python2 is being installed on the system)
2021-05-11 19:24:02,503 INFO failed to remove python-dev
2021-05-11 19:24:02,503 INFO checking for libpython-dev (auto_inst=False)
2021-05-11 19:24:02,503 INFO removing libpython-dev because None is being installed
2021-05-11 19:24:02,503 DEBUG Removing 'libpython-dev' (None is being installed on the system)
2021-05-11 19:24:02,544 INFO failed to remove libpython-dev
2021-05-11 19:24:02,544 INFO checking for libpython-stdlib (auto_inst=False)
2021-05-11 19:24:02,544 INFO removing libpython-stdlib because None is being installed
2021-05-11 19:24:02,545 DEBUG Removing 'libpython-stdlib' (None is being installed on the system)
2021-05-11 19:24:02,586 INFO failed to remove libpython-stdlib
2021-05-11 19:24:02,586 INFO checking for libpython-dbg (auto_inst=False)
2021-05-11 19:24:02,586 INFO checking for python-dbg (auto_inst=True)
2021-05-11 19:24:02,586 INFO checking for python-doc (auto_inst=True)
2021-05-11 19:24:02,586 INFO checking for python-minimal (auto_inst=True)
2021-05-11 19:24:02,586 INFO installing python-is-python2 because python-minimal was installed
2021-05-11 19:24:02,586 DEBUG Installing 'python-is-python2' (python-minimal was installed on the system)
2021-05-11 19:24:02,629 INFO removing python-minimal because python-is-python2 is being installed
2021-05-11 19:24:02,629 DEBUG Removing 'python-minimal' (python-is-python2 is being installed on the system)
2021-05-11 19:24:02,629 INFO failed to remove python-minimal
2021-05-11 19:24:02,629 INFO checking for python-dev (auto_inst=True)
2021-05-11 19:24:02,630 INFO installing python-dev-is-python2 because python-dev was installed
2021-05-11 19:24:02,630 DEBUG Installing 'python-dev-is-python2' (python-dev was installed on the system)
2021-05-11 19:24:02,671 INFO removing python-dev because python-dev-is-python2 is being installed
2021-05-11 19:24:02,671 DEBUG Removing 'python-dev' (python-dev-is-python2 is being installed on the system)
2021-05-11 19:24:02,671 INFO failed to remove python-dev
2021-05-11 19:24:02,671 INFO checking for libpython-dev (auto_inst=True)
2021-05-11 19:24:02,671 INFO removing libpython-dev because None is being installed
2021-05-11 19:24:02,671 DEBUG Removing 'libpython-dev' (None is being installed on the system)
2021-05-11 19:24:02,671 INFO failed to remove libpython-dev
2021-05-11 19:24:02,671 INFO checking for libpython-stdlib (auto_inst=True)
2021-05-11 19:24:02,671 INFO removing libpython-stdlib because None is being installed
2021-05-11 19:24:02,671 DEBUG Removing 'libpython-stdlib' (None is being installed on the system)
2021-05-11 19:24:02,671 INFO failed to remove libpython-stdlib
2021-05-11 19:24:02,672 INFO checking for libpython-dbg (auto_inst=True)
2021-05-11 19:24:03,298 ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: '**E:Error**, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.'
2021-05-11 19:24:03,298 **DEBUG abort called**
```

Note: I used `sudo dpkg -l  | grep ^h` to check for held packages and there were none.

Before this I ran without errors.

```sh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Do I need to install python? If so what package name should I use? Any and all suggestions welcome.

Comment: Please clarify your releases, 10.04 is mentioned in your heading and it upgraded to 10.10 or 12.04 (next release or next LTS release)

Comment: @guiverc based on tags it's probably 18.04 to 20.04 upgrade.

Comment: Yeah I agree @WinEunuuchs2Unix but I was always told assume nothing....   (assumption leads to .... *censored*....)

Comment: @guiverc Yes teachers in school told us "assume" makes a "donkey" out of "u" and "me". I wrote a script last year assuming I could easily upgrade 16.04 directly to 19.04 without using 16.04 to 18.04 to 19.04 two step process. Yeah it can be done but it's not easy! Based on that experience I know a 1 point poster couldn't write a script to upgrade 10.04 to 20.04 in a single step.

Comment: Why not download the image, make a bootable USB  and clean install from that?

Comment: I see a bug for this problem but it says it was fixed. What version of `ubuntu-release-upgrader-core` are you running? Run `dpkg -l ubuntu-release-upgrader-core` to find out.

Comment: The title should be 18.04 to 20.04.

Comment: I would try this upgrade again and you'll likely find it's fixed (ie. possibly related to bug 1928397 which has been fixed)

Comment: Turns out there was a bug in the build which has been fixed. I tried again and successfully upgraded to 20.04.